# How to use 'after' function to create interceptor in Pedestal

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I wish to make a new Pedestal interceptor to be run during the leave stage. I wish to modify the context to add a token string to the base of each html page (for use in 'site alive' reporting).

From the Pedestal source code [here](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/interceptor/src/io/pedestal/interceptor/helpers.clj) I see this function:

```
(defn after
 "Return an interceptor which calls `f` on context during the leave
 stage."
 ([f] (interceptor {:leave f}))
 ([f & args]
    (let [[n f args] (if (fn? f)
                    [nil f args]
                    [f (first args) (rest args)])]
      (interceptor {:name (interceptor-name n)
                 :leave #(apply f % args)}))))
```

So I need to provide it with a function which will then be inserted into the interceptor map. That makes sense. However, how can I write this function making reference to the context when 'context' is not in scope?

I wish to do something like:

```
...[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers :as h]...

(defn my-token-interceptor []
  (h/after
    (fn [ctx]
      (assoc ctx :response {...}))))
```

But 'ctx' is not in scope? Thanks.

Comment: You need to "install" the interceptors in your routes. Can you show that part of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `after` doc is clear on this.

```
(defn after
 "Return an interceptor which calls `f` on context during the leave
 stage."
```

your `f` will receive `context` as its first argument. You can access `context` inside `f` by using `f`'s first argument.

below is a sample of a `f` function: `token-function`, that will be supplied to `h/after` and because `h/after` returns interceptor, I create a 'my-token-interceptor' by calling `h/after` with `token-function`

```
...[io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers :as h]...

(defn token-function
  ""
  [ctx]
  (assoc ctx :response {}))

(def my-token-interceptor (h/after token-function))

;; inside above token-function, ctx is pedestal `context`
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, we no longer think the `before` and `after` functions are the best way to do this. (All the functions in `io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers` are kind of unnecessary now.)

Our recommendation is to write interceptors just as Clojure map literals, like so:

```
(def my-token-interceptor
  {:name ::my-token-interceptor
   :leave (fn [context] (assoc context :response {,,,}))})
```

You can see that the `after` function doesn't add anything in terms of clarity or explanatory value.

Of course you can use a function value in the map rather than making an anonymous function right there:

```
(defn- token-function
  [context]
  (assoc context :response {,,,}))

(def my-token-interceptor
  {:name  ::my-token-interceptor
   :leave token-function)})
```